# Django passing data through the url, not finding page in url patterns

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm trying to pass an object's id through the url, but its not able to find the page even after it tries the path when it goes through its patterns

Error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in GroomingService.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='Home']
appointment-Maker/
account/
admin-home
view_appointment/<id>/
login/ [name='Login Page']
registration/ [name='Registration Page']
logout [name='Logout Page']
The current path, adminview_appointment/21/, didn’t match any of these.
```

GroomingService.urls

```
#urls
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', Home_view, name="Home"),
    path('appointment-Maker/', include('appointmentApp.urls')),
    path('account/', include('accountApp.urls')),
    path('admin-home', include('adminApp.urls')),
    path('view_appointment/<id>/', viewAppointment_view), #this is the page it is not finding


    path('login/', Login_view, name='Login Page'),
    path('registration/', Registration_view, name='Registration Page'),
    path('logout', Logout_view, name='Logout Page')
]
```

adminApp/views.py viewAppointment_view

```
def viewAppointment_view(request, id):
    appointments = Appointment.objects.get(id = id)
    context = {
        'appointments' : appointments
    }
    return render(request, "admin_templates/viewappointment.html", context)
```

templates/admin_templates viewappointment.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<a>appointment view</a>
{% endblock %}
```

templates/admin_templates adminhome.html (the link is clicked through this page)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<a>this is the admin page</a>
<br>

{% for a in appointments %}
<a href="adminview_appointment/{{a.id}}/">Client name:{{a.client_dog_name}}</a><br> {% comment %} this is the link that is clicked {% endcomment %}
{% endfor %}


<br>
<a>find month</a>
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ monthyear }}
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">click</buttom>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

If I'm missing anything please let me know, I had the path at the adminApp/urls.py earlier

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.adminhome_view, name="Admin Home"),
]
```

but moved it to where it was trying to find the urls. I have no idea why this might not be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `view_appointment/{{a.id}}`, not `adminview_appointment/{{a.id}}`, but it is better to make use of the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url). You can give the view a name:

```
path('view_appointment/<int:id>/', viewAppointment_view, name='view_appointment'),
```

and then refer to it in the template:

```
<a href="{% url 'view_appointment' id=a.id %}">Client name:{{a.client_dog_name}}</a><br>
```